Как правильно вызвать команду в контроллере
Есть команда
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use App\Repository\ImageRepository;
use App\Repository\BattleCardRepository;
use App\Repository\CollectionCardRepository;

#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:cover:download',
    description: 'Download image for cover',
)]
class CoverDownloadCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(
      private ImageRepository $imageRepository,
      private BattleCardRepository $battleCardRepository,
      private CollectionCardRepository $collectionCardRepository,
      private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {

    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

        $battle_cards = $this->battleCardRepository->findAll();
        $collection_cards = $this->collectionCardRepository->findAll();
        $link = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$_ENV['token']}/getFile?file_id=";
        $file_link = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{$_ENV['token']}/";
        $ch = curl_init();

        foreach ($battle_cards as $card) {
            $covers = [$card->getDefaultCover(), $card->getSilverCover(), $card->getGoldCover(), $card->getDiamondCover()];

            foreach ($covers as $item) {
                if($item) {
                    $img_db = $this->imageRepository->findOneBy(['cover' => $item]);

                    if(!$img_db) {
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link . $item);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                        $response = curl_exec($ch);
                        $data = json_decode($response, true);

                        if ($data['ok']) {
                            $io->writeln($data['result']['file_path']);
                            $image_url = $file_link . $data['result']['file_path'];
                            $path_info = pathinfo($image_url);
                            $ch = curl_init();

                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                            $image_data = curl_exec($ch);

                            curl_close($ch);

                            $save_path = "./public/images/{$item}.{$path_info['extension']}";
                            file_put_contents($save_path, $image_data);

                            $this->imageRepository->createImg($item, $path_info['extension']);

                            $this->entityManager->flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($collection_cards as $card) {
            $img = $card->getPhoto();
            $img_db = $this->imageRepository->findOneBy(['cover' => $img]);

            if(!$img_db) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link . $img);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                $data = json_decode($response, true);

                if ($data['ok']) {
                    $io->writeln($data['result']['file_path']);
                    $image_url = $file_link . $data['result']['file_path'];
                    $path_info = pathinfo($image_url);
                    $ch = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                    $image_data = curl_exec($ch);

                    curl_close($ch);

                    $save_path = "./public/images/{$img}.{$path_info['extension']}";
                    file_put_contents($save_path, $image_data);

                    $this->imageRepository->createImg($img, $path_info['extension']);

                    $this->entityManager->flush();
                }
            }
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        $io->success('You have a new command! Now make it your own! Pass --help to see your options.');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}

Если я ее просто запускаю из докер контейнера php bin/console app:cover:download так, то все работает, но мне нужно дать возможность запускать ее по api.
Делаю класс контроллера
#[Route('/api')]
class ApiCardsController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(
      private CommandExecutor $commandExecutor
    ){}

    #[Route('/covers-download', name: 'coversDownload', methods:'GET')]
    public function coversDownload(): Response
    {
        $output = $this->commandExecutor->execute('app:cover:download');

        return $this->json(['status'=> true, 'message' => 'ok', 'output' => $output]);
    }
}

И делаю сервис который вызывается
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application as SymfonyApplication;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class CommandExecutor
{
    private $application;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->application = new SymfonyApplication($kernel);
        $this->application->setAutoExit(false);
    }

    public function execute(string $commandName, array $arguments = []): string
    {
        $input = new ArrayInput(array_merge(['command' => $commandName], $arguments));
        $output = new BufferedOutput();

        $this->application->run($input, $output);

        return $output->fetch();
    }
}

Когда обращаюсь по api ссылке почему-то падает ошибка(при том что из консоли все ок)

Warning:
file_put_contents(./public/images/AgACAgIAAxkBAAEBA4dmcbO89PLUSdj_
\n  kpRr8XWPvwtuYwACdN4xG3QeiEpIk4hH5hObBgEAAwIAA3kAAzUE.jpg): Failed
to open s  \n  tream: No such file or directory
\n
\n\nException trace:\n  at
/var/www/html/src/Command/CoverDownloadCommand.php:76\n
App\Command\CoverDownloadCommand-\u003Eexecute() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:279\n
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command-\u003Erun() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1047\n
Symfony\Component\Console\Application-\u003EdoRunCommand() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:123\n
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application-\u003EdoRunCommand()
at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:316\n
Symfony\Component\Console\Application-\u003EdoRun() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:77\n
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application-\u003EdoRun()
at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:167\n
Symfony\Component\Console\Application-\u003Erun() at
/var/www/html/src/Service/CommandExecutor.php:25\n
App\Service\CommandExecutor-\u003Eexecute() at
/var/www/html/src/Controller/Api/ApiCardsController.php:21\n
App\Controller\Api\ApiCardsController-\u003EcoversDownload() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:183\n
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-\u003EhandleRaw() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:76\n
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-\u003Ehandle() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:182\n
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel-\u003Ehandle() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php:35\n
Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\HttpKernelRunner-\u003Erun()
at /var/www/html/vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29\n require_once()
at /var/www/html/public/index.php:5\n\napp:cover:download\n\n

Так же попробовал выдать права из контейнера
chmod -R 0777 public/images
Не помогло

Попробуйте по другому. Создайте сервис который делает то что нужно. И используете этот сервис в команде и контроллере. Нет смысла дергать команду из контроллера.

Абсолютно согласен с предыдущим комментарием. А если о вашей конкретной проблеме, то попробуйте umask использовать, однако, это не решит вашу фундаментальную проблему с правами, для консольной команды на сколько я понимаю их хватает (вроде под копотом, если ничего не путают, то используется как раз umask), но на выполнении через сервер их недостаточно. Под это советую завести отдельный вопрос и описать как вы настраиваете права, приложить Dockerfile и т.д.
